# Random background image using jQuery for Elementor and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

Trying to load a new background image on page refresh using jQuery. Spent hours on it and can't get it to work. In my child theme I have a folder for my images and a separate js folder.

I've got a full-height Elementor section with an ID of `#background`.

**My js file**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = new Array('absolute path to images/bg_01.png', 
   'https://absolute path to images/bg_02.png', 
   'absolute path toimages/bg_03.png');
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  $("#background").css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + images[num] + ')');
});
```

**Child theme functions.php**:

```
function load_js_assets() {
  if( is_page( ID ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-js', 'absolute path to /js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
  } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
```

Where might I be going wrong?

Something to add in the `header.php`? `footer.php`?

Comment: Do you have id="#background" or id="background" - the first is incorrect. Any erros in console? Any PHP errors?

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure myself how to annotate that in the question. My ID is "background". As for errors, haven't checked. Not quite sure where to look. Using Firefox

Comment: Ah, backgroundImage is JavaScrip - background-image is css

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#background").css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + images[num] + ')');
```

to

```
$("#background").css('background-image', 'url(' + images[num] + ')');
```

Comment: Thanks Zed. Still not working. . .even with the change recommended. I checked the console and got this error: _Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function_. Not sure what that means. What in the js code is incorrect?

Comment: Got it figured out. Had to do with WP's noConflict() mode. I changed the `$` selector to `jQuery`. Working great now! Heads up, it works weather or not backgroundImage or background-image is used.